# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'EMAIL' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel please give the solution
This is user controller code when i submit the form i am getting email is null but i am inserting email.

there is no laravel issue i think its mysql issue

```
<?php
namespace App\http\Controllers;

  use App\User;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

     class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function postSignUp(Request $request)
   {
     $email = $request['email'];
     $first_name = $request['first_name'];
     $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

     $user = new User();
     $user->email = $email;
     $user->first_name = $first_name;
     $user->password = $password;

     $user-> save();

     return redirect()-> back();
   }

     public function postSignIn(Request $request)
   {
   }

   }
```

This is migrate table.

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
   {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
    }
 }
```

This is my html file

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <h3>Sign Up</h3>
  <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  <lable for="email">Your Email</lable>
  <input class="form-control" type="email" name "email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <lable for="first_name">Your first name</lable>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
  </div><div class="form-group">
  <lable for="password">Your Password</lable>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name "password" id="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
  </form>
  </div>
```

AND THIS I S ROUTE

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

 Route::post('/signup', [
       'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
       'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

Comment: did you tried dd($email); ? what are you getting?

Comment: It may be due to the HTML form name error to for the Email field ...

Comment: Please update your post with result of `dd($request->all());` inserted in the beginning of `PostSignUp()`. Also, please show appropriate route and form HTML from a view.

Comment: div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
   <h3>Sign Up</h3>
   <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
   <lable for="email">Your Email</lable>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name "email" id="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <lable for="first_name">Your first name</lable>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
   </div><div class="form-group">

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "first_name" => "123456"
  "_token" => "lBNPyvBlvyrOpnVWngLZfCtHddwPpWwJbEOVMYC7"
]

Comment: Have provide with the solution check it out :)

Comment: Your HTML seems to be incorrect as i have suggested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your HTML is wrong.
>   Replace:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name "email" id="email">
<input class="form-control" type="password" name "email" id="password">
```

With

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email">
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
```

After that replace your Controller like this:

```
$email= $request->input( 'email' );
```

Comment: same issue i change type to email

Comment: Have you replace the two lines what i have given in my answer

Comment: Your HTML Format seems incorrect in the `name "email"` and hence the email fields is not been passed to the controller.

Comment: It should be `name="email"` for email and `name="password"` for password fields...

Comment: Actually email array is going as null

Comment: Try using like this method: `$email= $request->input( 'email' );` in the controller..

Comment: I have spotted you the Error that response -> Try using like this method: $email= $request->input( 'email' ); in the controller

Answer (score 0):

to get the email value you should first  add an `=` btw name and "email" and then inside the controller replace the `$email = $request['email']`  by `$email = $request->input('email');`

Comment: it was a silly mistake. thanks @celia it worked with just =

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issues is as you are using

```
$email = $request['email'];
```

You have to pass a default value if it is empty like below or make the mysql filed accept null value

```
$name = Input::get('email', 'default@gmail.com');
```